# Jquery Accordion - Collapse on click again

Tags: jquery, accordion

So, I have the following code:

```
$(".btn-slide-1").click(function(){
    $('div[id^="panel"]').slideUp("slow");
    $('ul#menu li a').removeClass("active");
    $("#panel-about").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});

$(".btn-slide-2").click(function(){
    $('div[id^="panel"]').slideUp("slow");
    $('ul#menu li a').removeClass("active");
    $("#panel-products").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});

$(".btn-slide-3").click(function(){
    $('div[id^="panel"]').slideUp("slow");
    $('ul#menu li a').removeClass("active");
    $("#panel-specs").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});
```

Essentially I was looking to get this streamlined, but all it does is when you click on an a class it open the div relating to this. It all works OK, but if I click on the same item again, it just collapses and then instantly reopens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can warp it in a condition check.

```
$(".btn-slide-1").click(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $('div[id^="panel"]').slideUp("slow");
        $('ul#menu li a').removeClass("active");
        $("#panel-about").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope, that still collapses it, and then opens it right up again.

Comment: @Palemo I also added a refactored one - so you do not need to bind click event individually for each btn-slide - help to keep your code DRY. The link is http://jsfiddle.net/3aH5r/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think your jquery code should look like this

```
i$(".btn-slide-1").click(function(){
    var currentActive = $(this).hasClass("active");
    $('div[id^="panel"]').slideUp("slow");
    $('ul#menu li a').removeClass("active");

    if(!currentActive){
       $("#panel-about").slideToggle("slow");
       $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
    }
    return false;
});
```

what happens is you slide up all panels and remove the 'active' class on the 'a' tags
so when these lines execute,

```
$("#panel-about").slideToggle("slow");
$(this).toggleClass("active");
```

the panel is currently collapse so, slideToggle will expand it again